# Class not found after copying libraries to libraries folder (NetBeans)

Tags: java, classloader, netbeans-8, cdc

New to Java. As a DBA it's not the world I normally live in, but I IBM's CDC offering provides a set of libraries for any real automation.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSTRGZ_11.3.0/com.ibm.cdcdoc.chcclp.doc/tasks/setupembeddedscript.html

I can import and run my application so far if I reference the .jar files from their absolute path. i.e. where the IBM CDC application was installed. But if I copy the .jar files to my libraries folder in NetBeans, I get the below error:

The import commands don't error and everything seems fine until I run it. Any advise would be appreciated.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/osgi/util/NLS
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.ibm.replication.cdc.scripting.EmbeddedScript.executeWithStatus(EmbeddedScript.java:231)
    at com.ibm.replication.cdc.scripting.EmbeddedScript.execute(EmbeddedScript.java:159)
    at cdcinterface.CDCInterface.main(CDCInterface.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.osgi.util.NLS
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 15 more
C:\Users\roberdan\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

This is line 53 of run.xml:

```
<java classpath="${classpath-translated}" classname="${classname}" dir="${work.dir}" jvm="${platform.java}" fork="true" failonerror="${java.failonerror}">
            <jvmarg value="-Dfile.encoding=${encoding}"/>
            <redirector inputencoding="${encoding}" outputencoding="${encoding}" errorencoding="${encoding}"/>
            <jvmarg line="${run.jvmargs}" />
            <arg line="${application.args}" />
            <syspropertyset>
                <propertyref prefix="run-sys-prop."/>
                <mapper from="run-sys-prop.*" to="*" type="glob"/>
            </syspropertyset>
        </java>
```

Comment: FYI: I right click on the project in Netbeans > Properties > Libraries > Add Jar/Folder. I then select the 17 .jar files with the option of "Copy to libraries folder" which is in a lib folder in the root of my project.

Comment: classpath is a parameter that can be used while launching java program and points to compiled classes source directories. I do not use NetBeans but I believe that you can see the exact command line arguments with which java is being launched. are you sure that the classpath contains the needed directory where this library is located?

Comment: Thanks. I initiate it from the run icon in NetBeans. The only output I can see is what I pasted above.

Comment: A the end end it does refer to line 53 of run.xml. I've added that above now as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issues was with the IBM classes themselves. You can get the classes either from the server install, or the client install. I copied them from the client install but should have been from the server. Once I did that, all was good.